# Django Rest CORS with Vue JS

Tags: django, vue.js

I have a django rest framework api running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and a Vue JS app running on http://127.0.0.1:5173/. When I make a request from the vue app I get the **origin has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**
I have installed django cores and below are the setting in my settings.py

Installed Apps

```
"corsheaders",
```

Middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

And allowed

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Vue JS Code

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'; # In axios.js

async login() {
    const response = await axios.get('users', {
                username: this.username,
                password: this.password
            });
    console.log(response)
},
```

Comment: CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before any middleware that can generate responses such as Django’s CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise’s WhiteNoiseMiddleware. If it is not before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these responses. Use it just below the session middleware.

Comment: It is setup as such as shown.

Answer (score 0):

In doc write

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS: bool
```

If True, all origins will be allowed. Other settings restricting allowed origins will be ignored. Defaults to False.

Setting this to True can be dangerous, as it allows any website to make cross-origin requests to yours. Generally you'll want to restrict the list of allowed origins with CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS or CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES.

Previously this setting was called CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL, which still works as an alias, with the new name taking precedence

https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#cors_allow_all_origins-bool

Comment: I have tried different combinations from the shared link but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

So after hours of stressing and frustrations, this is how I solved this. I maintained my Vue JS code as below

```
async login() {
            const response = await axios.post('auth/login/', {
                        username: this.username,
                        password: this.password
                    });
            console.log(response)

        },
```

and in my Django settings.py file I had to add these two lines:

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = "*"
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:5173',
]
```

Since Alex pointed out that `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True` can be dangerous hence the `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` block.